# How to achieve multiple inheritance?

Tags: android, multiple-inheritance

I looked at several questions, posts, etc but wasn't able to get the solution to my problem
I.e
How do i achieve this:-

```
public class Songlist extends Activity,BroadcastReciever{
}
```

**I am looking for a solution without inner class cause i tried it but i am not able to do it properly.**

I get some constructor errors when i try to do the inner class stuff.

I tried my best but i wasn't able to get a solution so under compulsion i have to ask this to others.

Comment: NO its not possible. BTW why do you need to do that?

Comment: You should post a separate question with your actual 'some constructor errors' and get that working as there's no multiple inheritance in Java.

Answer (score 1):

In Java there is no multiple inheritence out of the box. You might be able to simulate it by using interfaces.

Comment: I have never worked with interfaces, and i don't know what are they. What could i do.

Comment: Read up on them. They are really handy. If you are familiar with C++, they are similar to abstract base classes.

Comment: Suppose i write:-     public class Songlist extends Activity implements BroadcastReciever{}, will it work.

Comment: Trial and Error. ;)

Comment: BroadcastReceiver and Activity are both classes, not interfaces, so implements will not work.